# Laravel Inertia Vue Precognition File Upload

Tags: laravel, validation, file-upload, inertiajs

i am trying to upload a pdf file through a form. I am using Laravel Inertia Vue Stack and Laravel precognition.
these are my FormRequestValidation

```
return [
  'type' => 'required|in:Antidadah,Bas',
  'aim' => 'required|string',
  'target_visitor' => 'required|integer',
  'location' => 'required|string',
  'kumpulan' => 'required|string',
  'ref_no' => 'required|string',
  'status_id' => 'required|exists:statuses,code',
  'file' => [
     ...$this->isPrecognitive() ? [] : ['required'],
     'file',
     'mimes:pdf',
]
```

this is my form in vue

```
const form = useForm(
    props.request ? "patch" : "post",
    props.request
        ? route("requests.update", props.request)
        : route("requests.store"),
    {
        type: props.request ? props.request.type : null,
        aim: props.request ? props.request.aim : null,
        target_visitor: props.request
            ? props.request.target_visitor
            : null,
        location: props.request ? props.request.location : null,
        kumpulan: props.request ? props.request.kumpulan : null,
        ref_no: props.request ? props.request.ref_no : null,
        status_id: props.request ? props.request.status_id : null,
        user: props.request ? props.request.user : null,
        note: props.request ? props.request.note : null,
        file: null,
    },
);
```

When I submit the form without a file, all works well, but when I submit the form with a file, all other field will be invalidated. Can anyone point me what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know about this module, to submit a file with methods different than post you should use the hidden input field with name of the method.
When you simply validate, useForm submits Ajax (content application/Json). Otherwise it submits Formdata (with regular Post method).
Ir should be explained in the documentation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).